# How do I deploy an R code model in Salesforce Einstein Analytics Plus? Or find another alternative to Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, salesforce, tableau-api, salesforce-einstein

**tl;dr** *I want to deploy "live" model results in Python and R, and while Salesforce Einstein advertises this functionality for R and Python, I have only found support for Python. Shiny is too expensive to justify for our limited R-language requirements.  Does Einstein R support actually exist?*

**UPDATE:** Tableau has a separate solution from Einstein Analytics that hosts both R and Python - see answer below.  Not a feature-rich direct competitor to Shiny, but that's not our use-case.

According to the documentation for Salesforce Einstein Analytics Plus (aka Tableau CRM AI Analytics), data scientists can upload (operationalize) their Python, R, and Matlab code, as described here:

https://www.tableau.com/solutions/ai-analytics (see the section on "Data Science" at the bottom of the page).

I signed up for a trial of Einstein Analytics Plus, and found a link to the "Model Manager."  Using Model Manager to deploy Python-language models is well-documented here:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_edd_model_upload_prepare.htm&type=5

For Python, this seems to match the advertised functionality.  But there is no indication of how to deploy R language models, which may be part of my team's use case.

I would like to find the equivalent method for deploying an R-language model in Einstein.  Particularly, is there some other Salesforce / Tableau product I should try, or is this a feature that is simply not available in the trial version.  Unlike Python deployment, searching the documentation has not yielded answers.

Alternatively, we're only interested in Einstein R support is because it appears to be about 1/10 the cost of Shiny, which is hideously expensive.  So any recommendations regarding lightweight alternatives to Shiny would also be helpful.

TIA for anyone who can shine a light on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: There is actually a separate feature in Tableau that is different from Einstein Analytics which supports both R and Python, documentation here:

https://help.tableau.com/current/prep/en-us/prep_scripts.htm